# bc crypt "undefined data" error when importing library with node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, hash, bcrypt

I am trying to use the bcrypt library in my node (react frontend) app. When I import the library and run the function to hash my password on my local server it works fine. However once I upload my server file to my production environment in heroku it crashes and provides the following generic error:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:1599:59

I have read this may be due to a webpack issue?

I receive the error the moment I import the library, so even if I do not use bcrypt in any function, I still get the error.

I am importing it like so

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
```

and when running on my local server (where it works) I am hashing the password like this

```
const saltRounds = 10;

bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    // Storing hashed password in DB.
});
```

Looking for any help as to why importing this (or any other hashing library) is causing the data undefined error the moment it is imported.

thank you!

Comment: The npm `bcrypt` library requires Node.js; it can't be run out of the box in frontend code in the browser. Why would you need `bcrypt` in the frontend?

Comment: (You could use a pure-JavaScript implementation like https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs if you do need it in the frontend.)

Comment: @AKX i am only using it on my node server file (I was just highlighting that the front end is react but i guess its irrelevant). I am using yarn for package install if that makes a difference. I will look into your JS version. Thank you

Comment: Okay, it wasn't quite clear that you weren't trying to use `bcrypt` in the frontend. You don't need to look at `bcryptjs` then. Then it's a bug in some frontend code you're not showing us; you're getting `undefined` from somewhere and you're trying to access `.data` on it.

Comment: Thanks, assumed it was front end error but when I completely remove the front end function call that would trigger the bcrypt in the backend I am still getting the error. If I take all functions out and just import bcrypt or any other hashing library on my server file I get the same error. Not sure how it’s interacting with my front end still.